# Pandas find id-index for which time-index starts in specific month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have some data as CSV in the format `id, time, var`. I then went on and created a Multiindex DataFrame roughly of the form below

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def time(t):
    return pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01T12") + pd.to_timedelta(t, "d")


arrays = [
    np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]),
    np.array([time(0), time(1), time(396), time(365), time(31), time(365)]),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 1), index=arrays, columns=["var"])
df.index.names = ["id", "time"]
df
```

```
                          var
id  time
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00   -0.505903
    2019-01-02 12:00:00    0.626197
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00    0.461155
    2020-01-01 12:00:00    0.569891
3   2019-02-01 12:00:00   -1.079466
    2020-01-01 12:00:00    0.721466
```

Given this, **I would like to find all id's for which the earliest entry is in January**, to then plot the trajectory represented by the id for only trajectories which start in January.

As a note, I think the time is actually sorted, while the id is not. Not sure if that changes anything tho.

i.e.

```py
df.pseudo_filter(start_month="January")
```

```
                          var
id  time
1   2019-01-01 12:00:00   -0.505903
    2019-01-02 12:00:00    0.626197
2   2020-02-01 12:00:00    0.461155
    2020-01-01 12:00:00    0.569891
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) by the month of `min` `time`

```py
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).min().month == 1)
```

Or

```py
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).min().month_name() == 'January')
```

Out:

```
                             var
id time                         
1  2019-01-01 12:00:00  0.410113
   2019-01-02 12:00:00 -0.572882
2  2020-02-01 12:00:00 -0.801334
   2020-01-01 12:00:00  1.312035
```

---

To add the filter as a new function to your dataframe

```py
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("pseudo")
class Pseudo:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    def filter(self, start_month):
        return (self._obj.groupby(level=0)
                    .filter(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1).min()
                    .month_name() == start_month))
```

Then you can use

```py
df.pseudo.filter(start_month='January')
```

Out:

```
                             var
id time                         
1  2019-01-01 12:00:00 -1.314898
   2019-01-02 12:00:00  0.810314
2  2020-02-01 12:00:00 -1.214327
   2020-01-01 12:00:00 -0.678823
```

Comment: Thanks! Already the first part was what I was looking for. But the second part is super interesting too, I possibly need this in some form more often in the upcoming months and thus a new method might bring some welcome convenience. :)